# how to add ip address to log stream name in cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, ip-address, amazon-cloudwatch, cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

While i try to set up cloudwatch in one of my servers , i cannot get my server ip address append the log stream name.

For example : IP-ADDR_myapplicationlog.

To achieve the above i tried **{ip_address}_myapplicationlog** , but this returns 127.0.1.1 which is not my actual ip_address.
The log stream file name which appears in AWS console is :  127.0.1.1_myApplicationLog.

{hostname} works as expected but i am not able to retrieve the ip address.
Config attached below:
[config snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZ487.png)

Answer (score 2):

The follwoing values can be suffixed or prefixed to the log name.
({instance_id}, {hostname}, {ip_address})
While seting up the agent , we select custom name and add the above for example:{ip_address}_apacheLogs

Make sure the host file entries are correct.As mentioned in the question above the Id address always showed 127.0.1.1 due to incorrect host entry.